# Why does a logger Java need check isDebugEnabled()?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging

Why java logger need check

```
if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
   log.debug("Debug message");
}
```

instead call directly `log.debug("Debug message");`?

Comment: to prevent Logging when you dont need your application to log.

Comment: @SudiptaMondal when root level log is info, debug log still write to file bro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't. Typically, you would call `log.isDebugEnabled()` in cases when you need some extra code to log what you want:

```
if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
    for (...) {
        // Some heavy logic that is only needed when logging things
        log.debug("Debug message");
    }
}
```

This way you never trigger the extra logic when it's not needed.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@1615903](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1615903/1615903)'s answer:

You can configure different [levels](https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/Logger.html#isDebugEnabled--) of logging. For some environment you might want to disable DEBUG level and logging engine (SLF4J) wouldn't put those messages into log but the code (`log.debug("...")`) would still be executed, which is completely useless with disabled DEBUG level. Using `isXXXEnabled()` you can avoid excess work.